# pyspark sql concat empty col

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

With pyspark sql functions, I'm trying to do this

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as sf
query = sf.concat(sf.lit("UPDATE abc"), sf.lit(" SET col1= '"), sf.col("col1"), sf.lit("'"), sf.lit(", col2= '"), sf.col("col2"), sf.lit("'"), sf.lit(" WHERE col3 = 1")
myDataframe = myDataframe.withColumn("query", query)
query_collect = myDataframe.collect()
conn = createConnexion(args, username, password)
try:
    for row in query_collect:
        print(row["query"])
        conn.run(row["query"])
        conn.commit()
```

But it doesn't works. It work with just col1, but col2 make an error because sometime, this col2 is empty (null)
query column is null and conn.run(row["query"]) throw this exception :
None 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'

I'm trying to use pyspark sql.when like this but this is the same issue :

```
myDataframe = myDataframe.fillna(value="NO_SQL")
query = sf.concat(sf.lit("UPDATE abc"), 
sf.lit(" SET col1= '"), 
sf.col("col1"), 
sf.lit("'"), 
sf.when(sf.col("col2") != "NO_SQL", sf.concat(sf.lit(", col2= '"), sf.col("col2"), sf.lit("'"))), 
sf.lit(" WHERE col3 = 1")
```

Edit for @Linus :
I'm tryin this

```
@udf(returnType=StringType())
def sql_worker(col1, col2, colWhere):
    col2_setting = ", {col2} = '{col2}'" if col2 is not None else ""
    return f" UPDATE entreprise SET {col1} = '{col1}'{col2_setting} WHERE abc = {colWhere} "

def aaa(dynToInsert, colonne, args, username, password, forLog):
    dfToInsert = dynToInsert.toDF()
    dfToInsert.withColumn("query", sql_worker(sf.col('col1'), sf.col('col2'), sf.col('col3')))
```

But I have this exception : Invalid returnType: returnType should be DataType or str but is StringType({})

Thanks

Comment: use `func.coalesce('col2', func.lit(''))`. it will replace the nulls with blank which won't affect the sql string, and the sql will receive it as blank

Comment: Thanks samkart. It correct the exception but this is not the solution because I want to avoid the "set col2" if col2 is null.

Comment: have you tried creating the `query` column using `when().otherwise()`?

Comment: It works with when().otherwise(). At the beginning, I'm trying without the otherwise and it is an error. Thanks.

Comment: feel free to answer your own question so that others can benefit from your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with when().otherwise(). At the beginning, I'm trying without the otherwise and it is an error. Thanks.

```
query = sf.concat(
    sf.lit("UPDATE def"),
    sf.lit(" SET " + colonne + " = "), sf.col(colonne),
    sf.when(sf.col("abc").isNull(), "").otherwise(sf.concat(sf.lit(" , abc = '"), sf.col("abc"), sf.lit("'"))),
    sf.lit(" WHERE " + colonne + " = "), sf.col(colonne)
    )
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can solve ur issue:

```
@udf(returnType=StringType())
def sql_worker(col1, col2):
    col2_setting = ", col2 = '{col2}'" if col2 is not None else ""
    return f" UPDATE abc SET col1 = '{col1}'{col2_setting} WHERE col3 = 1 "

data = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('abc', 'lll',),
    ('ddd', 'xxx',),
    ('qqq', None),
], ['col1', 'col2'])

data.withColumn("query", sql_worker(col('col1'), col('col2'))).show(10, False)
# +----+----+-------------------------------------------------------------+
# |col1|col2|query                                                        |
# +----+----+-------------------------------------------------------------+
# |abc |lll | UPDATE abc SET col1 = 'abc', col2 = '{col2}' WHERE col3 = 1 |
# |ddd |xxx | UPDATE abc SET col1 = 'ddd', col2 = '{col2}' WHERE col3 = 1 |
# |qqq |null| UPDATE abc SET col1 = 'qqq' WHERE col3 = 1                  |
# +----+----+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't works, I have an exception. I edit my post.